# org mode export settings in properties

Tags: latex, org-mode

I'm trying to use properties in org mode to set export settings. The [the org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html) makes it sound like export settings can be set at multiple levels, including properties regarding individual trees (as well as that more specific settings overwrite more general ones). Specifically i want to turn off breaks in some trees to not get my lists messed up in latex export. But no matter how I use properties ("\n:" being the shortcut for org-export-preserve-breaks), they have no effect (same goes for when using export settings, such as those regarding emphasis). Neither

```
#+options: \n:nil
* title
:PROPERTIES:
:\n:       t
:END:

 point 1
 point 2
 point 3
```

nor

```
#+options: \n:nil

* title
#+property: \n t

 point 1
 point 2
 point 3
```

results in

```
 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents


 \section{title}

 point 1\\
 point 2\\
 point 3\\
 \end{document}
```

instead i get

```
 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents


 \section{title}

 point 1
 point 2
 point 3
 \end{document}
```

Are export settings just not meant to be in properties or is there a way to set them on a tree level?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. There are two problems:

- subtree properties don't override the global properties when you export the whole document; they apply only when you export the subtree alone (`C-c C-e C-s l l` to export the subtree to latex e.g.).
- only certain export options can be overridden through properties; they are the ones that contain a KEYWORD in the value list of the option in`org-export-options-alist` (see the documentation for that variable: `C-h v org-export-options-alist RET`. preserve-breaks is not one of them: its KEYWORD value is nil in that list. BTW, the property name is obtained from the KEYWORD value by prepending `EXPORT_` to it.

I actually modified the source in ox.el to add a PRESERVE_BREAKS keyword to the appropriate entry, and did some testing by setting the corresponding EXPORT_PRESERVE_BREAKS property in the subtree, to come up with the above description. But it may well be that I missed something: corrections are welcome.